# How to quick navigate through all interfaces on godoc site

Tags: go, godoc

Is there any way to quick navigate through all interfaces in a package?

On `godoc.org`, now `pkg.go.dev`, there isn't an "interface" type in the documentation index. The in-page navigate interface recognizes interface as no type. So currently I'm using browser searching "interface" as a keyword but functions which accepts `interface{}` as a parameter is also included.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try searching instead on the browser for

```
interface {
```

This avoids matching with interface{} due to the space before the bracket.

I'm not sure if any browsers will ignore the space difference however both Firefox and Chrome worked for me.

Comment: Wow! I really didn't think about that! Thank you